# Getting Duplicate results on join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables(VW_ATP_DOWNLOAD_NOREQCAT and VW_MM_SALES_GRID) which have to columns in common 1.Material 2.Size_Literal  I only want the material and size_literal from table #2 (VW_MM_SALES_GRID) - VW_MM_SALES GRID which I am joining to has the following columns:

Material,
Technical_index,
Size_literal,
active_flag,
size_conversion,
record_date_time,
nrf_sizecode,
technical_index_2digits

What I am hoping to produce is all of the 'A' fields along with, most importantly the size field from 'm' because M contains all sizes where as A contains only sizes with an on hand value - I want to see all the sizes and null if there is no value in the 'A' Table.  If I just run a table with this material I get the results:

size L = 45
size M = 51

I know there is a size S and I need to see that null so I can convert to a zero value but when I run the below query it just duplicates ALL sizes with the values 45 and 51....at a bit of a loss.  Thanks.

Query:

```
 SELECT A.MATERIAL, 
       M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
       AVAIL_DATE,
       A.AVAIL_QTY,
       A.STOCK_CATEGORY

FROM   VW_ATP_DOWNLOAD_NOREQCAT A LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_MM_SALES_GRID M ON A.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL

WHERE  M.MATERIAL = 'AA2721'

AND A.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60381000','A60382000')

AND  A.AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 90

AND   A.MATERIAL = 'AA2721' 

AND  M.ACTIVE_FLAG IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY A.MATERIAL, 
         M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
         AVAIL_DATE, 
         A.AVAIL_QTY,
         A.STOCK_CATEGORY
```

My results:

AA2721              L   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 45  A60382000
AA2721              L   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 51  A60382000
AA2721              M   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 45  A60382000
AA2721              M   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 51  A60382000
AA2721              S   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 45  A60382000
AA2721              S   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 51  A60382000

When I run with only the 'A' Table:

```
SELECT A.MATERIAL, 
       A.SIZE_LITERAL, 
       A.DATEPART(mm,AVAIL_DATE) AS 'MONTH',
       A.AVAIL_QTY,
       A.STOCK_CATEGORY

FROM   VW_ATP_DOWNLOAD_NOREQCAT A LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_MM_SALES_GRID M ON A.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL

WHERE  M.MATERIAL IN ('AA2721')

AND A.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60381000','A60382000')

AND  A.AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 90

AND   A.MATERIAL ='AA2721'
```

I get:

```
AA2721              L   8   45  A60382000       
AA2721              M   8   51  A60382000
```

When I run with the Join I get:

```
AA2721              L   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 45  A60382000       
AA2721              L   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 51  A60382000       
AA2721              M   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 45  A60382000       
AA2721              M   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 51  A60382000       
AA2721              S   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 45  A60382000       
AA2721              S   2017-08-26 00:00:00.000 51  A60382000
```

Large should have 45 and Medium should have 52, Small which is a valid size should be null because it isn't in the join table....not sure what I did wrong.  Thanks!

Results of M table w/ only material in question:

```
MATERIAL           TECHNICAL_INDEX SIZE_LITERAL ACTIVE_FLAG SIZE_CONVERSION_MATERIAL_ID RECORD_DATE_TIME        NRF_SIZECODE TECHNICAL_INDEX_2DIGITS
------------------ --------------- ------------ ----------- --------------------------- ----------------------- ------------ -----------------------
AA2721             480             2XS          NULL        KC                          2017-07-29 06:16:40.000 20900        21
AA2721             500             XS           NULL        KC                          2017-07-29 06:16:40.000 20901        23
AA2721             520             S            X           KC                          2017-07-29 06:16:40.000 20902        25
AA2721             540             M            X           KC                          2017-07-29 06:16:40.000 20903        27
AA2721             560             L            X           KC                          2017-07-29 06:16:40.000 20904        29
```

Comment: just too add - the IS NOT NULL on the joined query is because the size grid has 'inactive sizes' so I  need to filter those out.

Comment: it will be clear to see M table data also.. but i think you should add  A.size_literal=M.size_literal  on the join condition

Comment: I will try the size join

Comment: its the strangest thing - no matter what I add it won't show the "small" size from the M table I tried right outer join and left outer, reversing the commands

Answer (score 0):

I think the M Table should be the pivot table. And I moved some conditions to join condition.

Can you try this?

```
SELECT A.MATERIAL, 
       M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
       A.AVAIL_DATE,
       A.AVAIL_QTY,
       A.STOCK_CATEGORY
FROM   VW_MM_SALES_GRID M LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_ATP_DOWNLOAD_NOREQCAT A 
    ON A.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
    AND A.SIZE_LITERAL = M.SIZE_LITERAL
    AND A.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60381000','A60382000')
    AND A.AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 90

WHERE  M.MATERIAL = 'AA2721' AND  M.ACTIVE_FLAG IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY A.MATERIAL, 
         M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
         AVAIL_DATE, 
         A.AVAIL_QTY,
         A.STOCK_CATEGORY
```

Comment: that did the trick - thanks a ton!  pivot table makes perfect sense.  Curious why moving WHERE conditions to the join made the difference? Appreciate it.